# CSS, make left & right background images slide out of view for small screens

Tags: css, background-image

Here is a mockup of what I am trying to achieve as the window shrinks, using two separate images for the left and right:

[image: screen getting smaller]

For a wide screen the images will stick to the left and right, but as the screens shrinks they will slide out of view. Here is a mockup if any genius out there can figure out a pure css solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/1/

`<div id="bg1"><div id="bg2"></div></div>`

CSS would be preferred if it's even possible, otherwise I can do something basic in javascript.

Cheers!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution whose most advanced CSS requirement is media queries, which it appears you're already willing to accept:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="bg" id="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg" id="bg2"></div>
    <div id="content">
        ...         
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
}
html, body{
    background:#f8e9a4;
    margin: 0;
}
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#bg1{
    background: url("http://sunny-kids-wordpress-theme.dtbaker.net/wp-content/themes/sunny-kids/images/background_leaves_left.png") no-repeat left top;
    width: 113px;
    left: 0;
}
#bg2{
    background: url("http://sunny-kids-wordpress-theme.dtbaker.net/wp-content/themes/sunny-kids/images/background_leaves_right.png") no-repeat right top;   
    width: 122px;
    right: 0;
}
#content{
    width:400px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin: 20px auto;
    min-height:500px;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #bg1{
       right: 50%;
        margin-right: 220px;
        width: auto;
        background-position: right top;
    }
    #bg2{
         left: 50%;
        margin-left: 220px;
        width: auto;
        background-position: left top;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    #content{
        width:90%;
        }
    img{
     max-width:100%;   
    }
}
```

Here's a **[Working Example via jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/6/)**.

**UPDATE:** Here's **[another version](http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/7/)** that ditches `#bg1` and `#bg2` for the `body:before` and `body:after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using some not-widely-implemented technology, you can try [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc):

http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/2/

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #bg1{
        background-position:-webkit-calc(50% - 285px) top;
        background-position:-moz-calc(50% - 285px) top;
        background-position:-ms-calc(50% - 285px) top;
        background-position:calc(50% - 285px) top;
    }
    #bg2{
        background-position:-webkit-calc(50% + 285px) top;
        background-position:-moz-calc(50% + 285px) top;
        background-position:-ms-calc(50% + 285px) top;
        background-position:calc(50% + 285px) top;
    }
}
```

[Compatible table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

(I picked `285px` because that fits my Chrome best. You can of course pick other pixel that you think works better.)

If you're uncomfortable with this, you may need to separate `#bg1` and `#bg2` from `#content` (i.e. put them as standalone elements instead of content wrapper).

---

Edit:

Here's another solution that doesn't use `calc()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/3/

```html
<div id="bg1"></div><div id="bg2"></div>

<div id="content">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```css
#bg1{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background: url("http://sunny-kids-wordpress-theme.dtbaker.net/wp-content/themes/sunny-kids/images/background_leaves_left.png") no-repeat left top;
}
#bg2{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background: url("http://sunny-kids-wordpress-theme.dtbaker.net/wp-content/themes/sunny-kids/images/background_leaves_right.png") no-repeat right top;    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #bg1{
        background-position:right 220px top 0px;
    }
    #bg2{
        background-position:220px 0px;
    }
}
```

But it turns out [four value `background-position` is not implemented wider than `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Mind blown. That is amazing! Would adding `background-position:0 -1000px` at the start hide the background for browsers that do not support `calc()`? (eg: http://jsfiddle.net/TV8sB/4/ )

Comment: @dtbaker Yes :) And I've added another solution that doesn't use `calc()`.